# Expand/Close user-control tree

Tags: c#, winforms, tree, treeview

The below code works to load xml files of a tree view in the user-control. Somehow i feel the code for expand/close is not well coded.  Is there any other way of coding this in a more clean form?

```
try{
    this.tvTraceSelect.Progress = true;
    this.tvTraceSelect.UnitsPath = unitsPath;
    this.tvTraceSelect.TracesPath = tracesPath;
    this.tvTraceSelect.View = Traces.View.Files;
    this.tvTraceSelect.TreeView.CollapseAll();
    if (this.tvTraceSelect.TreeView.Nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        this.tvTraceSelect.TreeView.Nodes[0].Expand();
        if (this.tvTraceSelect.TreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            this.tvTraceSelect.TreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Expand();
            if (this.tvTraceSelect.TreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                this.tvTraceSelect.TreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Expand();
                if (this.tvTraceSelect.TreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    this.tvTraceSelect.TreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Expand();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}catch (Exception _excep)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, "An error occured during the initialization of the InitTracesView .\nDetails: " 
            + _excep.Message + "\n\n" + _excep.StackTrace, "Initialization error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using recursion?

Comment: @Charlie Kilian:Can you propose me some solution.

Comment: First let me ask, what are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you want to expand all nodes in the tree. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Charlie Kilian:Sam has given the right answer, thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void ExpandFirst(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
   if (nodes.Count > 0)
   {
      nodes[0].Expand();
      ExpandFirst(nodes[0].Nodes);
   }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
ExpandFirst(this.tvTraceSelect.TreeView.Nodes)
```

Comment: :I just want to simplify my code in the selection process...because it works well.

Comment: :your code expands expand all the tree when i loaded it. This is not good for the user to see auto expand.

Comment: You only want to see the first child node of each level expanded?

Comment: This code isn't correct, it only expands the first node.  Use foreach instead.  Using ExpandAll() is the better way.

Comment: @HansPassant - I agree that if expanding all nodes is the goal, then ExpandAll() would be the better way to go.  However, OP posted a comment (which was deleted) that they didn't want the entire tree expanded.  They just want to reproduce what the code is doing now, which seems to be expanding only the first child at each level.  Hence why my method is called ExpandFirst, not ExpandAll...